# SELECT + INSERT in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is what I'm using now

```
public function nuevaPlantilla(){
    $query = $this->sql->prepare("SELECT max(did) as nuevodid FROM ".self::tabla_plantillas);
    $exc = $query->execute();
    if (!$exc){
        return false;
    }
    $resultado = $query->get_result();
    $datos = $resultado->fetch_all();
    $did = ($datos[0][0]*1)+1;
    $query = $this->sql->prepare("INSERT INTO ".self::tabla_plantillas." (did, quien, tipo_usuario, did_filtro, valor, pagina) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    if (!$query){
        return false;
    }
    $query->bind_param("isssss", $did, $this->quien, $this->tipo, "", "", $this->qh);
    $exc = $query->execute();
    $query->close();
    return $exc;
}
```

It works, but, is it possible to make the same thing with only one query?

PLEASE DO NOT SUGGEST ME TO USE AUTO_INCREMENT ID. Because more than one row would have the same did.

Comment: technically, no. you cannot insert into or delete from the same table that you are simultaneously selecting from.

Comment: Yes, it is: The syntax is: `insert into destination_t (col1, col2) select max(id), 'other_values'  from source_t`

Comment: @MarcB: It is possible: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4540/1

Comment: It worked @juergend I just added +1 to max(did). Is any way to have the did as 1 if the table is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
insert into destination_table (id, col2, col3)
select * from 
(
  select coalesce(max(id),0)+1,
         'other_value',
         3
  from source_table
) x
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98fd1/1)

Comment: I'm curious. What is the `x` for at the end?

Comment: You need to name a subquery. I used `x` as name. It is necessary for the syntax. Thats all.

Comment: This is the exact query I used, I don't need a subquery. "INSERT INTO ".self::tabla_plantillas." (did, quien, tipo_usuario, did_filtro, valor, pagina) SELECT coalesce(max(did),0)+1, ?,?,?,?,?,? FROM ".self::tabla_plantillas

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table (field, field)
SELECT field, field  FROM table
WHERE field='something';
```